# Determine physical location of Razor view in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've created my own Razor view class, thus:

```
public abstract class MyWebViewPage : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage
{
    public MyWebViewPage() 
    {
    }
}
```

I use this class in my cshtml file, thus:

```
@inherits MyWebViewPage
<html>
    ...
</html>
```

I want to determine the physical location of the cshtml file in the constructor of the class, but don't seem to be able to get a handle on anything in the base class that might tell me.  Any ideas?

I'm trying to work out the Area name and folder name of the view (e.g. Areas/MyArea/Views/MyViews/MyView.cshtml).  The pertinent bits being "MyArea" and "MyViews".

I'm currently porting an application to use Razor views and I used to be able to do what I needed because the class name of the view was something along the lines of:

ASP_Areas_MyArea_Views_MyViews_MyView

But with Razor it's just:

ASP_MyView

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I've added what I'm trying to achieve to the question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to look at the `VirtualPath` property. It will not be available when the constructor gets invoked, but you can override `ConfigurePage` and do any processing there.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I did indeed find what I was looking for by overriding ConfigurePage and using parentPage.VirtualPath (using 'this' gave me the _Layout.cshtml, as I'm using Layouts).