# ASP.NET MVC3 Physical Location of View from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view, filepath

What is the proper way to get the physical location of the View that will be served by a MVC action from inside the action?

I need the last modified time of the file for sending response headers.

Comment: Note, this question does not dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135450/determine-physical-location-of-razor-view-in-mvc3 that question is about being inside the view and not inside the controller.

Comment: I may be wrong but that wont be avalaible until post-action execute, or OnActionExecuted. I suppose you could loop through all of the registered ViewEngines and try finding the views based on the ViewLocation collection, but thats all manual

Comment: Also does not dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529417/asp-net-mvc-getting-last-modified-date-fileinfo-of-view this question might be for MVC1, the Request.PhysicalPath returns an invalid file location, it just treats my route as if it was a file request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper way to the get physical location of a view is to map its virtual path. The virtual path can be retrieved from the `ViewPath` property of `BuildManagerCompiledView` (`RazorView` derive from that class, and your `IView` instances will therefore typically have that property).

Here is an extension method that you can use:

```
public static class PhysicalViewPathExtension
{
    public static string GetPhysicalViewPath(this ControllerBase controller, string viewName = null)
    {
        if (controller == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("controller");
        }

        ControllerContext context = controller.ControllerContext;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
        {
            viewName = context.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
        }

        var result = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(context, viewName, null);
        BuildManagerCompiledView compiledView = result.View as BuildManagerCompiledView;

        if (compiledView != null)
        {
            string virtualPath = compiledView.ViewPath;
            return context.HttpContext.Server.MapPath(virtualPath);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Use it something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string physicalPath = this.GetPhysicalViewPath();
    ViewData["PhysicalPath"] = physicalPath;
    return View();
}
```

or:

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    string physicalPath = this.GetPhysicalViewPath("MyView");
    ViewData["PhysicalPath"] = physicalPath;
    return View("MyView");
}
```

Comment: How much work would caling `ViewEngines.Engines.FindView` be doing, so I could get this answer without actually needing to execute the result?

Comment: That should not be very expensive. Are you not intending to execute the view?

Comment: @ChrisMarisic I've updated my answer. It now shows how to use the same approach but without executing the view.

Comment: I was looking at something similar too, but your extension method is a very clean usage. I'm using the path to find to last modified time of the view to be used as part of a 304 not modified calculation.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic Great! Just keep in mind that any dynamic data rendered by the view could give you problems with such a calculation.

Comment: If-None-Match for resource, If-Modified-Since for html.

Answer (score 0):

That could work:

```
private DateTime? GetDate(string controller, string viewName)
{
    var context = new ControllerContext(Request.RequestContext, this);
    context.RouteData.Values["controller"] = controller;
    var view = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(context, viewName, null).View as BuildManagerCompiledView;
    var path = view == null ? null : view.ViewPath;
    return path == null ? (DateTime?) null : System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(path);
}
```